# Handlebars three arrays in one loop

Tags: rust, handlebars.js, rust-rocket

I have a Rust structure that looks something like this:

```rust
struct Root{
    as: Vec<A>,
}

struct A {
    bs: Vec<B>,
    cs: Vec<C>,
}

struct B {
    strings: Vec<String>,
}


struct C {
    strings: Vec<u32>,
}
```

and i'm trying to get output using Rocket.rs and Handlebars templating.

My handlebars template currently looks like this, but it doesn't work.

```html
{{#each as}}
    {{#each bs}}
        <h4>{{@index}}</h4>
        <pre>{{bs.@index}}</pre>
        <pre>{{cs.@index}}</pre>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

I get the following error `Error: Error rendering Handlebars template 'index' Error rendering "index" line 28, col 18: invalid digit found in string`, which probably has to do with the `@index` variables I'm using in the HBS tags.

Is there any other way I could only get one item out of two arrays and place them side-by-side without having to alter my structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. It looks like that for each `A` Object in the `as` Array that you would like to iterate over each element of `bs` and `cs`. This assumes that `bs` and `cs` have the same length for any `A`.

If this is what you want then I think your problem is that you are trying to access a `cs` from within the context of a `bs`. Within the `{{#each bs}}` block, the context is the current `B` Object. As a `B` does not have a `cs`, you need to step-up a context level so that you return to the context of the `A` which holds the `bs` and the `cs`. In Handlebars, you [change the context](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context) using a path, like `../`.

A simplified template that accesses the `bs` and the `cs` at each index of `bs` for each `A` would be:

```
{{#each as}}
    {{#each bs}}
        <h4>{{@index}}</h4>
        <pre>{{lookup ../bs @index}}</pre>
        <pre>{{lookup ../cs @index}}</pre>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Note: I used the [lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) for both the `bs` lookup and the `cs` lookup for consistency. However, as we are within the context of the `bs`, we could simply reference it with `.`. As in:

```
<pre>{{.}}</pre>
<pre>{{lookup ../cs @index}}</pre>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/w59f42j7/) for your reference.

Comment: I'm not even sure what I was trying to achieve myself, but your answer makes it clear that it's doable. I had three arrays of the same size and was trying to display them side by side in `<td>` of the table. Thanks for the answer and the fiddle!